# Преобразование в time

Tags: php

Подскажите есть способ перевести значение к примеру 2018-01-01 к виду записи time() (http://php.net/manual/ru/function.time.php)?

Comment: strtotime('2018-01-01');

Comment: Спасибо, все работает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *есть способ перевести значение к примеру 2018-01-01 к виду записи time() ?*

- Вариант 1: `echo (new DateTime('2018-01-01'))->getTimestamp();`
- Вариант 2: `echo strtotime('2018-01-01');`

Первый вариант предпочтительней *([цитата из оф.документации](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strtotime.php)*):

> `strtotime()` не рекомендуется использовать для математических операций. Целесообразно использовать *[DateTime::add()](http://php.net/manual/ru/datetime.add.php)* и *[DateTime::sub()](http://php.net/manual/ru/datetime.sub.php)* начиная с PHP 5.3, или *[DateTime::modify()](http://php.net/manual/ru/datetime.modify.php)* в PHP 5.2.

Comment: Спасибо, вопрос уже решил